# docker-compose is creating files with permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, development-environment

I'm using docker-compose as my development environment for my rails application so I don't need to install the future requirements on my own computer. The problem is that when I run, for example, `docker-compose run app rails g migration FooBar`, the migration file is created with permission so that I can't edit it without permission, and for me this is a problem, I wish this did not happen.

I understand why this occurs and this is not under discussion, what I want is know if I can create my files through docker-compose without permission to access it.

I don't know if I'm using the docker-compose in a wrong way, I'm a beginner with docker and maybe what I'm wanting to do don't make sense, if that's case could someone tell me how I could proceed to run my rails application and execute rails commands with docker.

Comment: can you show the file by doing a `ls -l filename` ?  It is likely a umask setting, but hard to see without that info.

Comment: After run `docker-compose run app rails g controller test` and `ls -l app/controllers/` my output was: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root            49 May  2 09:51 test_controller.rb`. Normal files have this permission: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 lucaspeixotot lucaspeixotot  302 Apr 30 18:54 application_controller.rb`.

Comment: are you then logging in as root or another user.  if another user, you should ideally chown -R another_user /your_app_dir